# How to scp from Windows 7 with private key without password?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, scp

I have a public and private key in *X:\secure*. Straight `ssh` with the private key works and I connect okay:

```
ssh -i X:\secure\id_rsa remoteuser@remote.server.com
```

The remote server is all set up for ssh and has the public key from *X:\secure\id_rsa.pub* added to */etc/ssh/authorized_keys/remoteuser*.

However, when I try to send a file over using

```
scp somefile.txt -i X:\secure\id_rsa remoteuser@remote.server.com:~
```

I get prompted for password.

**Question:** Is there a way to scp a file over seamlessly, without a prompt, just like ssh connection is established using a private key?

Comment: Are you prompted for the account password, or the SSH key passphrase?

Comment: account password

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Winows 10 machine, connecting to a Ubuntu server.
I've set it up so that I can only connect with a private key with a passphrase.

I'm using cmder and this works in Windows:

```
scp -i ~\.ssh\privatekey foobar.txt linuxuser@server:/home/linuxuser
```

**~.ssh\** referes to **C:\Users\.ssh\**

Comment: I found PuTTY's openssh format works fine for the private key, although .ppk does not.

Answer (score 1):

i am on linux so i can not test this but have you tried:

`scp -i X:\secure\id_rsa somefile.txt remoteuser@remote.server.com:~`

i'm pretty sure you have to put the options before the source file.  if you're getting a password prompt then the key is not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving my scenario  as an answer here , any future readers may get benefited . File copied from  Windows system to the Amazon EC2 instance running in Ubuntu.

```
C:\Users>scp -i "C:\aws\keys\JenkinsSrv.pem" jenkins-cli.jar ubuntu@ec2-18-222-189-18.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu
```